# get google account image using google api

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

At the very first time,I'm trying to get my google account profile picture by using google api. So I have referred [Refer](http://25labs.com/tutorial-implementing-google-api-using-oauth-2-0-in-php/) this site.

so in my google-plus-access.php:

```
   <?php

    require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php'; // or wherever autoload.php is located

    session_start();
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Google+ PHP Starter Application");

    $client->setClientId('MY_CLIENT_ID');
    $client->setClientSecret('MY_SECRET_KEY');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/G-api');
    $client->setDeveloperKey('MY_DEV_KEY');

    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));
    //$plus = new apiPlusService($client);
    $plus = $client -> createAuthUrl();
    if(isset($_REQUEST['logout']))
    {
        unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }

    if(isset($_GET['code']))
    {
        echo $_GET['code'];
        $client->authenticate();
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
    {
        echo $_SESSION['access_token'];
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
      $me = $plus->people->get('me');
      echo $me;
      $optParams = array('maxResults' => 100);
      $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public', $optParams);

      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else {
      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($authUrl); // this block is running!!!
      echo '</pre>';
    }
    echo "</br>";
```

?>

And in my index.php:

```
  <?php
     include('google-plus-access.php');
  ?>
   <img src="<?php  echo(substr($me['image']['url'],0,stripos($me['image']['url'],'?sz='))); ?>?sz=200" />
```

but i'm getting the result as:

```
   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FG-api&client_id=887633147241-8ragvhdi97lga3n829qogpl5aoima7l5.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.me&access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto
```

In my console I'm getting the below error:
[image]

My output scree is looking like this :

[image]

**EDIT:**

In my console i'm getting `GET http://localhost/G-api/%3Cbr%20/%3E%3Cb%3ENotice%3C/b%3E:%20%20Undefined%20…/G-api/index.php%3C/b%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E7%3C/b%3E%3Cbr%20/%3E?sz=200 403 (Forbidden)` this.

These things are done in local.So some body making me scared that we can't do this is local and we have create domain for that.So kindly help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code  `$me` is created in the **if** `// this block is running!!!`
  is in the **else**.

You are trying to use **$me** which hasn't been created.

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
      $me = $plus->people->get('me');   //Daimto: This doesn't run so you cant use it
      echo $me;
      $optParams = array('maxResults' => 100);
      $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public', $optParams);

      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($authUrl); // this block is running!!!
      echo '</pre>';
}
```

You also need to create a service, `$plus->people->get('me');` isn't going to work because $plus isn't a `Google_Service_Plus`.   You should check out the example found here [user-sample.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/user-example.php)

```
$googlePlus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
$userProfile = $googlePlus->people->get('me');
```

Comment: sorry i didn't get you ji:(

Comment: you are trying to use $me, you cant use it if its not created.  the code with the print_r runs. you can print $authUrl  but not $me

Comment: i'm new to this...this is my first try,then how can i solve it?

Comment: read my answer a few times then and you will be able to solve it I cant do more then give you code and tell you what's wrong.  Read The user-sample.php   it will walk you though using Oauth2 if you really think you need to use Oauth2.

Comment: if i use `Google_Service_Plus` i'm getting an error like `Catchable fatal error: Object of class Google_Service_Plus_Person could not be converted to string in`

Comment: In `$service->people->get('+LindaLawton')` what is `LindaLawton`?

Comment: its my google+ id :)  "me" is the default for the person authenticated but if you don't need to be authenticated you can use the persons id.

Comment: From where can i get the person id?

Comment: What are you doing does it require the users to be logged in?

Comment: and also how can i display it in my index.php file without using `me`, I mean what should be used instead of `me` in my `index.php`

Comment: yes after i have logged in,it should be get....have you saw the link `Refer` i have mentioned in my question ji?In that u can try it by clicking `demo`

Comment: follow the tutorial https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/user-example.php just change the Google_Service_Urlshortener to use Google_Service_Plus

Comment: i could not get the image because `index.php` it shows same error undefined variable `me`,even though i followed the link,because of not defininf `me` in anywhere

Comment: again that's because you have $me created in your if statement and the code is running for else.   you cant access a variable that hasn't been created yet.